# Creating a socket server and client which allows multiple connections via threads and Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to make a simple socket server so that it can have multiple TCP connections, via multithreading, but I can't seem to get it to work. It works for 1 client but i can't connect another client. I am new to this and any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;

    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);

    while (true) {
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        if (sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("i am the boss"))
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            Thread.currentThread().setName("boss");
            System.out.println("You have top priority boss");
        }
        else if(sentence!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("running thread name is:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());  
            System.out.println("running thread priority is:"+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());  
        }
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("server : " + modifiedSentence);
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}


public class Server {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        Responder h = new Responder();
        while (true) {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyServer(h, connectionSocket));

            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class MyServer implements Runnable {

        Responder h;
        Socket connectionSocket;

        public MyServer(Responder h, Socket connectionSocket) {
            this.h = h;
            this.connectionSocket = connectionSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (h.responderMethod(connectionSocket)) {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {
                connectionSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

}

class Responder {

    String serverSentence;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    synchronized public boolean responderMethod(Socket connectionSocket) {
        try {
            BufferedReader inFromClient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient =  new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            String clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

            if (clientSentence.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")) {
                return false;
            }

            if (clientSentence != null) {
                System.out.println("client : " + clientSentence );


            }

            serverSentence = br.readLine() + "\n";
            outToClient.writeBytes(serverSentence);
            return true;

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try and start another client? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is happening:

1. Server creates ServerSocket and keeps listening for client request
2. A **Client1** sends a request and server accepts it, creating an object of **Reponder** and passing it to a separate **MyServer** Thread.
3. The server starts listening for another client request on **ServerSocket** & the thread also waits for an input from the **Client1**. This leads to the thread holding a lock on the **Responder** object.
4. A new client **Client2** connects to Server. request is accepted on **ServerSocket** and the same object of **Responder** is passed to a separate thread to handle **Client2** request.

**Remember: The lock is still held on the Responder object by thread1**

Thus, unless **Client1** sends some data to the **Server**, the lock will exist. Once the **Client1** data is received by the server, the **Responder** object becomes available to the **thread2** and now its execution can begin.

But hold on, **Client1** still expects some data in return from the **Server**. Thus, even if **Client2** sends its data to server, the server won't reply to it unless it replies back to **Client1** first.

This leads to a situation where at a time only single Client-Server communication is observed.

---

Alternatively, you can create separate objects of the responder class to handle each client request.

You can put the separated statement (below) inside the while loop:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
```

---

```
        Responder h = new Responder();
```

---

```
        while (true) {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyServer(h, connectionSocket));

            t.start();
        }
    } }
```

This will create a separate responder for each client request and ultimately multiple client requests would be handled by the server, and observable too. :D

**NOTE: Your code will flawlessly work given there are continuous client requests coming and the server keeps replying to them.**